# Public visible custom attribute in maya custom image plane

Tags: c++, api, attributes, maya

I've been working on a custom image plane for maya, I need to load info from an external file, so I'm trying to create a custom attribute (string) for the user to input the path to the file.

I've declared this in the `customImagePlane.h`:

```
public:
    static  MObject     metaDataFile;
```

and initialized it in the `initialize` method:

```
MStatus customImagePlane::initialize()
{
    MStatus             stat;
    MFnTypedAttribute   attr;
    MFnStringData       stringFn;
    MObject defmsg  = stringFn.create("Input metadata file path");
    metaDataFile    = attr.create("metaDataFilePath", "datapath", MFnData::kString, defmsg, &stat);
    if(!stat) return stat;
    attr.setHidden          (false  );
    attr.setReadable        (false  );
    attr.setWritable        (true   );
    attr.setStorable        (true   );
    attr.setConnectable     (true   );
    attr.setChannelBox      (false  );
    attr.setInternal        (false  );
    attr.setUsedAsFilename  (true   );
    stat = addAttribute(metaDataFile);
    if (!stat) { stat.perror("addAttribute"); return stat;}
    return MS::kSuccess;
}
```

Right now the attribute is visible in the node editor or hypershade, but what I need is it to be visible within the extra attributes of the node so it is easily accesed by the users.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few hours thinking about stuff and trying some things it becomes that `restarting maya` made my attribute to be showed as It should. Loadind the `mll` is not so clean as it should be apparently.